# How do I add white spaces in Java Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm kind of new to this stuff, but what i want to do is just print out 00s from an int array that i created. I used a stringBuilder() to get rid of the commas and stuff. Now when I print out the numbers, they must have a space after every third 0 (a total of 11 0s). How do I do that? I only get a space after every 0 :-(.
here is what I got so far.

```
public class AccountNumber {

   private int[] digits = new int [11];

   // Methods Returns a string representation 
   public String toString() {
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       for (int value :digits) {
          builder.append(value + "   ");
       }

       String text = builder.toString();
       return text;
       //return Arrays.toString(digits);
   }

   public AccountNumber ( boolean random ){
   }
```

}

The output I want is `000 000 000 00`

I have another (main) class which creates the object for me. That's where the printing should happen.

```
public class Test1 {

   public static void main (String [] args) {

   //Random rand = new Random(false);
   AccountNumber acc = new AccountNumber(false);

   System.out.println(acc.toString());


   //AccountNumber.AccountNumber();
   }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please give example of input and output you want.

Comment: $ java Test1
000 000 000 00
$

Comment: I'm guessing that digits is an array, but the OP never shows this critical code. Why?

Comment: Where is the code where you read the command line parameters?

Comment: Sorry, the outpu i want is
000 000 000 00. My array is int with 11 elements. Would you like the whole code? not too long

Comment: I've subsequently retracted my close vote.  It's now at least answerable.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pretty print 11-digit account number on your `Account` class. You want to insert space after each 3 digits. If my assumptions are correct, you just need a counter to see which digit you're on and test if that digit can be divided by three:

```
int index= 0;
for (int value :digits) {
   builder.append(value);
   if (index %3 == 0) {
      builder.append(" ");
   }
   ++index;
}
```

This could be written in more clear way by using classic `for` loop, but I don't know which type your `digits` field is.

Comment: For it to be using the enhanced-for with an `int` as its marker, it would likely have to be either `int[]` or `Integer[]`.  Also, considering that the OP has edited in their full code, we can see now that it's `int[]`.